# Resource plugin not rendering correctly with https

Tags: email, grails

I'm attempting to use groovyPageRenderer.render() to render a temple with a model, so that I can email this rendered HTML using sendMail {}. Some of the banners we have include images and we add them using something like:

```
${resource(dir: 'images/email', file: 'background_body.gif', absolute: true)}
```

This is all good, and works fine in development. However, we wish to run the application over https, and despite setting grails.serverURL to "https://ourwebsite.com" (as indicated by the docs for Closure resource in ApplicationTagLib.groovy [from the grails-plugin-gsp]), it still tries to render the resources as available via http (which isn't available), only via https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this comment](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-resources/blob/master/grails-app/taglib/org/grails/plugin/resource/ResourceTagLib.groovy#L611) from the Resources plugin source, it appears that the plugin's `resource()` tag doesn't correctly support the attr `absolute`.  If you're running Grails v2.0 or above, Grails' `LinkGenerator` may be a workaround.  It's injected as `grailsLinkGenerator`, and can be invoked this way: `grailsLinkGenerator.resource(dir: '...', file: '...', absolute: true)`